# Distinguish between positive and negative infinity in opencl

Tags: floating-point, opencl, gpgpu

How can I test for positive or negative infinity specifically in opencl? On the reference card, I only see an option for isinf(), which does not distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isinf() does not give sign but you may try signbit() to see if the sign bit is set or not.

Comment: All right, that's what I'm talking about! I'll accept this once the timer lets me.